# Magento 1.9.3.4 possible issues

Tags: magento-1.9

A new `M1 version` was released with the following General Fixes. Now there's 1.9.3.4 and all the issues that I needed to be fixed are already fixed in this update.

1. Restored missing strip_tags functionality in the checkout JavaScript.
2. Changed how Magento validates form keys during the generic `five-step checkout process`. Previously, customer registration failed during standard checkout processing if form key authentication was enabled.
3. Magento now displays the `Allow_symlinks` message in the Admin message area as expected.
4. Magento now preserves the background transparency of uploaded images as expected. In 1.9.3.3: there's a black background in all PNG images including favicons. Haha!
5. Multiple Addresses when checkout form validation is enabled is now fixed. Before, you cannot check out.

Any possible issues in 1.9.3.4 that wasn't fixed yet?

Comment: @paj - that is for M 1.9.3.3.

Comment: yeah I copied the wrong url, was meant to be the v2 thread

Comment: @paj - oh ok. I didn't see that post prior to asking this question. :) I think we just asked on the same day, 2 days ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far there weren't any major issues reported with 1.9.3.4. No magento is polished so I would pull the trigger and install it.

1.9.3.3 had tons of complains within hours of release, while everyone is quiet about new 1.9.3.4, which is a good sign.

Comment: Hi Icon! Awesome! Thanks for sharing. Now it's not scary to upgrade my 1.9 m1 sites to 1.9.3.4. Will find out if there are any issues after the upgrade. I didn't upgrade to 1.9.3.3 before due to several issues that I've read online. :))

Answer (score 4):

since installing Magento 1.9.3.4 it results impossible to manage categories: when selecting one, by default, differently from the past, no tab is selected (description, products...), just a blank space. When modifying a description it doesn't allow to save changes. It's possible refreshing page, repeating the modify and then saving. Then, when moving to a new category you have to refresh again the page and hope is possible to save your changes. Never encountered this issue before installing 1.9.3.4 Please let me know if it's a common issue

Comment: @D Consulting - I also experienced this in Google Chrome. It's related to your browser's cookies. In Chrome, it's blank, but when I switched to Safari or Brave, I can see the category tabs / product tabs.Try switching to another browser, or clear your cookies (and everything) from the beginning of time.

Comment: Hello, I switched from Chorme to Chrome Canary and it doesn't work. I cleared the cache and it doesn't work. Can you help me? Really thanks

Comment: That's weird. Have you tried another Browser, like Safari?

Answer (score 2):

`Magento 1.9.3.3` was `1.9.3.2` + `supee-9767`

while `Magento 1.9.3.4` is `1.9.3.2` + `supee-9767 v2`

So the issues we have in `supee-9767` were there in `1.9.3.3` but some the issues were fixed `v2 patch`  , So still if you are using custom checkout extension or your checkout template files were in your theme folder may face `form-key` issue.

Comment: How can  i solve form-key error, i am not able to install 9787 v2

Comment: @zus are you using custom checkout extension ?

Comment: I am using PayPal..